# Failed to paginate data after filtering by a certain criteria - 2

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, pagination

Here's my DataSensor code that display data table with fields (id, temperature, humidity, brightness, createdAt). At first, when I don't use filter, all data will be loaded according to the page I click on (10 per page). When I use filter, the results return successfully but it doesn't paginate for me. I tried clicking to other page, it should have showed for me the paginated filter results, but it still called the getAllData function and output all data at that page. Please help me with this, thank you very much.

```
const DataSensors = () => {

    const [sensorData, setSensorData] = useState([]);
    const [isFilterInputModalOpen, setIsFilterInputModalOpen] = useState(false);

    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState('id');
    const [sortDirection, setSortDirection] = useState('asc');
    const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState(0);

    const [selectedField, setSelectedField] = useState('all');
    const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState('');

    const itemsPerPage = 10;

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3002/api/getAllData?page=${currentPage}&sortBy=${sortBy}&sortDirection=${sortDirection}`);
                const { totalCount, data } = response.data;
                setSensorData(data);
                setTotalCount(totalCount);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching sensor data:', error);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [currentPage, sortBy, sortDirection]);

    const handleSort = async (field) => {
        try {
            const direction = sortDirection === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
            setSortBy(field);
            setSortDirection(direction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sorting sensor data: ', error);
        }
    }

    const handleSearch = async () => {
        try {
            if (selectedField !== 'all' && !searchField) {
                setIsFilterInputModalOpen(true);
                return;
            }
            const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3002/api/searchData?field=${selectedField}&value=${searchField}`);
            setSensorData(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error searching sensor data: ', error);
        }
    }

    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCount / itemsPerPage);
    const paginate = (pageNumber) => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

    return (
        <div className='container__data'>
            <FilterInputModal isOpen={isFilterInputModalOpen} onClose={() => setIsFilterInputModalOpen(false)} />
            <div className="filter">
                <select value={selectedField} onChange={(e) => setSelectedField(e.target.value)}>
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="temperature">Temperature</option>
                    <option value="humidity">Humidity</option>
                    <option value="brightness">Brightness</option>
                    <option value="createdAt">CreatedAt</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" value={searchField} onChange={(e) => setSearchField(e.target.value)} />
                <button onClick={handleSearch}>Search</button>
            </div>
            <table className='data-table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
<th onClick={() => handleSort('id')} style={getHeaderStyle('id')}>
                            ID
                            {sortBy === 'id' && (
                                <span style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '5px' }}>
                                    {sortDirection === 'asc' ? '↑' : '↓'}
                                </span>
                            )}
                        </th>
                        <th onClick={() => handleSort('temperature')} style={getHeaderStyle('temperature')}>
                            Temperature
                            {sortBy === 'temperature' && (
                                <span style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '5px' }}>
                                    {sortDirection === 'asc' ? '↑' : '↓'}
                                </span>
                            )}
                        </th>
                        <th onClick={() => handleSort('humidity')} style={getHeaderStyle('humidity')}>
                            Humidity
                            {sortBy === 'humidity' && (
                                <span style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '5px' }}>
                                    {sortDirection === 'asc' ? '↑' : '↓'}
                                </span>
                            )}
                        </th>
                        <th onClick={() => handleSort('brightness')} style={getHeaderStyle('brightness')}>
                            Brightness
                            {sortBy === 'brightness' && (
                                <span style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '5px' }}>
                                    {sortDirection === 'asc' ? '↑' : '↓'}
                                </span>
                            )}
                        </th>
                        <th onClick={() => handleSort('createdAt')} style={getHeaderStyle('createdAt')}>
                            Created At
                            {sortBy === 'createdAt' && (
                                <span style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '5px' }}>
                                    {sortDirection === 'asc' ? '↑' : '↓'}
                                </span>
                            )}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {sensorData.map((data) => (
                        <tr key={data.id}>
                            <td>{data.id}</td>
                            <td>{data.temperature}</td>
                            <td>{data.humidity}</td>
                            <td>{data.brightness}</td>
                            <td>{new Date(data.createdAt).toLocaleString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div className="pagination">
                <button onClick={() => paginate(1)}><GrChapterPrevious /></button>
<button onClick={() => paginate(currentPage - 1)} disabled={currentPage === 1}><GrCaretPrevious /></button>
                {Array.from({ length: totalPages }, (_, index) => {
                    if (index + 1 === 1 || index + 1 === totalPages || (index + 1 >= currentPage - 2 && index + 1 <= currentPage + 2)) {
                        return (
                            <button key={index} onClick={() => paginate(index + 1)} className={currentPage === index + 1 ? "active" : ""}>{index + 1}</button>
                        );
                    } else if (index + 1 === currentPage - 3 || index + 1 === currentPage + 3) {
                        return <span key={index}>...</span>;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                })}
                <button onClick={() => paginate(currentPage + 1)} disabled={currentPage === totalPages}><GrCaretNext /></button>
                <button onClick={() => paginate(totalPages)}><GrChapterNext /></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DataSensors;
```

and here's my api code:

```
app.get('/api/getAllData', (req, res) => {
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
    const itemsPerPage = 10;
    const startIndex = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    const sortBy = req.query.sortBy || 'id';
    const sortDirection = req.query.sortDirection || 'asc';
    const sql = `SELECT * 
                FROM datasensors 
                ORDER BY ${sortBy} ${sortDirection}
                LIMIT ${itemsPerPage} OFFSET ${startIndex}`;
    const countSql = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalCount FROM datasensors`;
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error executing query: ', err);
            res.status(500).json({ err: 'Internal Server Error' });
        } else {
            console.log(result);
            db.query(countSql, (err, countResult) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error getting total count: ', err);
                    res.status(500).json({ err: 'Internal Server Error' });
                } else {
                    const totalCount = countResult[0].totalCount;
                    res.status(200).json({ totalCount, data: result });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

app.post('/api/searchData', async (req, res) => {

    const selectedField = req.query.field;
    const searchField = req.query.value;
    let sql;

    const dateFormatRegex = /^\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2} \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;

    if (selectedField === 'createdAt') {
        if (!isNaN(searchField)) return;
        if (!dateFormatRegex.test(searchField)) return;
        const formattedDate = searchField.split(' ')[1].split('/').reverse().join('-') + ' ' + searchField.split(' ')[0];
        sql = `SELECT * FROM datasensors WHERE createdAt = '${formattedDate}'`;
    } else if (selectedField === 'all') {
        if (!searchField) return;
        if (isNaN(searchField)) {
            if (!dateFormatRegex.test(searchField)) return;
            const formattedDate = searchField.split(' ')[1].split('/').reverse().join('-') + ' ' + searchField.split(' ')[0];
            sql = `SELECT * FROM datasensors WHERE createdAt = '${formattedDate}'`;
        }
        else {
            sql = `SELECT * FROM datasensors WHERE temperature = ${searchField} OR humidity = ${searchField} OR brightness = ${searchField}`;
        }
    } else {
        if (isNaN(searchField)) return;
        sql = `SELECT * FROM datasensors WHERE ${selectedField} = ${searchField}`;
    }

    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error executing query: ', err);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json(result);
        }
    });

});
```

i have tried to filter and it worked for me but the filter results doesn't paginate for me

Comment: Unlike `/api/getAllData`, your `/api/searchData` does not use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` to achieve paging.

Comment: I got what you mean, but suppose I have 100 records and want to find the temperature of 20, then the offset I don't know what its startIndex is because the values may not appear continuously together. When displaying the filter results, I clicked to page 2 and it called /getAllData of page 2 and distorted the results. I should have seen the results of /searchData returned on page 2. Please help me

Comment: `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` are applied _after_ the `WHERE` clause. I have not checked how you navigate to page 2 in a search.